# Obtain from a List custom Objects of a List of distinct String values of Two String fields of these Objects using Java-Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

Java stream on specific fields in a custom class object

I have an `ArrayList` of `Train` objects.

Each `Train` has three *fields*: `source`, `destination`, `cost`.

I want to get all the place names, i.e. all distinct *sources* + *destinations*.

I am using the below code, but as it can be observed, I'm using two streams to retrieve the data.

```java
List<String> destinations = list.stream()
    .map(x -> x.getDestination())
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> sources = List.stream()
    .map(x -> x.getSource())
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I was wondering how I could accomplish the same thing in a single stream? Can it be done using `flatMap`, or there's another way to achieve this?

```java
List<String> allPlaces = ?
```

Also, is this possible to use `Train` class without getters?

Comment: Have you tried mapping to a `Pair` type?

Comment: Do you want 2 separate lists(1 for sources, 1 for destinations) or 1(for both)?

Comment: @rostIvan i wanted a single list of just distinct places

Comment: @potato, please see the Mureinik answer.
It is possible without the getters of the Train class if instance variables are accessible

Comment: @rostIvan It's not a good practice in Java to access instance variables directly from outside the class.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, sure, but the question is not about good practices but rather a possibility

Comment: @rostIvan It implies both. The spirit of StackOverfow is to be the source of hi-quality answers. It seems like background OP is Python, hence it's important to explain how we approach Encapsulation in Java apart from saying that it is technically not to declare getters. Also, as replay to the solution you've recommended, there's a better alternative for addressing this problem - [*see*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613240/17949945).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had the right idea with `flatMap` - you can map a train to a stream that contains the source and destination, and then `flatMap` it to you "main" stream:

```java
List<String> allPlaces =
    trains.stream()
          .flatMap(t -> Stream.of(t.getSource(), t.getDestination()))
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: wow ! exactly what i wanted, thanks a lot!
will have to take a look at the Stream.of method

Comment: @potato Note that for each element of the stream, `flatMap` requires a new nested stream to be created, because that's how it consumes flattened elements. In addition `Stream.of()` required wrapping elements with an array (that how *varargs* works in Java). These overheads can be avoided by using method `Stream.mapMulty()`. [*See*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613240/17949945).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we can utilize Java 16 method [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), which is functionally similar to `flatMap()`. It's meant for transforming a single stream element into a group of elements.

Here's how implementation might look like:

```
List<String> places = trains.stream()
    .<String>mapMulti((train, consumer) -> {
        consumer.accept(train.getSource());
        consumer.accept(train.getDestination());
    })
    .distinct()
    .toList();
```

Contrary to `flatMap()` it doesn't consume a stream, but operates via `Consumer`. `mapMulti()` a recommended alternative to `flatMap()` for situations when a new stream `flatMap()` requires would contain only a few elements (like in this case when we have only two elements: source and destination).

A quote from the API Note:

> This method is preferable to `flatMap` in the following circumstances:
>
> - When replacing each stream element with a **small** (possibly zero)
>   number of elements. Using this method **avoids** the **overhead** of creating
>   a **new Stream instance** for every group of result elements, as required
>   by `flatMap`.

---

*Addressing peripheral question:*

> Also is this possible without the getters methods of class `Train`?

Sure, you can. But it's not a recommended practice to access instance fields directly. In Java we're using access modifier to hide and protect member-variables within the class, that's one of the aspects of [*Encapsulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Comment: I agree with you that in cases like this using `mapMulti` is preferred over `flatMap`.  It might be that the OP wasn't running Java 16 or perhaps better understood the other solution.